# Multiple class selectors not working CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a mobile responsive nav bar. When on mobile (screen<680px) the menu disappears (hidden by :

```
    ul.topnav li:not(:nth-child(1)){
        display: none;
    }
```

And when i click on the drop down icon the dropdownMenu() is triggered and it adds ***responsive*** to the **className** of **ui** and the nav bar is shown vertically as it's shown in the code:

```
    ul.responsive li {
        display: inline;
        float: none;
    }
```

It only works if i use **ul.topnav.responsive{}**. Why doesn't it work with **ul.responsive{}** ??

```css
/* ######## Nav bar ######## */
nav ul {
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.topnav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

ul.topnav li.topnav-right{
    float: right;
}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    min-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #666;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover{
    background-color: #0080ff;
    color: #fff;
}

ul.topnav li.dropDownIcon {
    display: none;
}

/* ###### Mobile styles ###### */

@media screen and (max-width : 680px) {
    ul.topnav li:not(:nth-child(1)){
        display: none;
    }

    ul.topnav li.dropDownIcon {
        display: block;
        float: right;
    }

    ul.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }

    ul.responsive li {
        display: inline;
        float: none;
    }

    ul.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="topnav" id="dropdownClick">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#singup">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#signin">Sign In</a></li>
            <li class="dropDownIcon"><a href="#" onclick="dropdownMenu();">&#9776;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <script>
        function dropdownMenu() {
            var x = document.getElementById("dropdownClick");

            if(x.className === "topnav"){
                x.className += " responsive";
            }else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the [specificify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your styles.

- First, you are disabling all `li` elements on mobile.
- Then, after clicking the menu, you want to display `li` elements.

Currently your styles have conflicting orders, so they use the rule with the highest specificify.

This:

```
ul.topnav li:not(:nth-child(1)) {
    display: none;
}
```

Has greater specificify than this:

```
ul.responsive li {
    display: inline;
}
```

So the first rule is taken into account. When you did:

```
ul.topnav.responsive li {
    display: inline;
}
```

It increased the specificity by one, so it works.

You can find a good specificity [calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) online.

If you want to increase your specificity without adding a different class, you can duplicate the `.responsive` selector.

```
ul.responsive.responsive li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Also, please use `classList.toggle` instead of manually changing selectors.

```css
/* ######## Nav bar ######## */

nav ul {
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.topnav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

ul.topnav li.topnav-right{
    float: right;
}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    min-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #666;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover{
    background-color: #0080ff;
    color: #fff;
}

ul.topnav li.dropDownIcon {
    display: none;
}

/* ###### Mobile styles ###### */

@media screen and (max-width : 680px) {
    ul.topnav li:not(:nth-child(1)){
        display: none;
    }

    ul.topnav li.dropDownIcon {
        display: block;
        float: right;
    }

    ul.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }

    ul.responsive.responsive li {
        display: inline;
        float: none;
    }

    ul.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="topnav" id="dropdownClick">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#singup">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#signin">Sign In</a></li>
            <li class="dropDownIcon"><a href="#" onclick="dropdownMenu();">&#9776;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <script>
        function dropdownMenu() {
            document.getElementById("dropdownClick").classList.toggle("responsive");
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: typo in the first line: specificity